# Sum of Total per Client

Tags: select, oracle-11g, subquery, where

I want to know the total of each product that each customer has bought and I don't know how to add the total per customer.

The tables are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENTES -- Customers
(   
    CODIGO NUMBER(4,0)  PRIMARY KEY,    -- customer ID
    NOMBRE VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,       -- number
    APELLIDOS VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,    -- surnames
    EDAD NUMBER(2,0) NOT NULL           -- age
);

CREATE TABLE PEDIDOS -- Orders
(
    NUM NUMBER(5,0) PRIMARY KEY,        -- order ID
    FECHA DATE NOT NULL,                -- date
    GASTOS_ENVIO NUMBER(5,2),           -- shipping costs
    FECHA_PREVISTA DATE NOT NULL,       -- expected (shipping) date
    TOTAL NUMBER(10,2) ,                -- total
    CLIENTE NUMBER(4,0),                -- customer ID

    CONSTRAINT CLIENTES_FK FOREIGN KEY (CLIENTE) REFERENCES CLIENTES (CODIGO)
);

CREATE TABLE PRODUCTOS -- Products
(
    CODIGO  NUMBER(5,0) PRIMARY KEY,    -- product ID
    NOMBRE  VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,      -- amount
    PRECIO   NUMBER(7,2) NOT NULL       -- price
);

CREATE TABLE LINEAS -- Lines
(   
    NUM NUMBER(2,0),                    -- line ID
    NUM_PEDIDO NUMBER(5,0),             -- order ID
    PRODUCTO NUMBER(5,0) NOT NULL ,     -- product ID
    CANTIDAD NUMBER(8,0) NOT NULL ,     -- customer ID
    IMPORTE NUMBER(6,2),                -- amount

    CONSTRAINT DETALLE_PK PRIMARY KEY (NUM, NUM_PEDIDO) , 
    CONSTRAINT PEDIDO_FK FOREIGN KEY (NUM_PEDIDO)
      REFERENCES  PEDIDOS (NUM) , 
    CONSTRAINT PRODUCTO_FK FOREIGN KEY (PRODUCTO)
      REFERENCES  PRODUCTOS (CODIGO) 
);
```

The query I am currently trying is:

```
SELECT c.CODIGO, pr.NOMBRE, COUNT (l.CANTIDAD) AS TOTALPEDIDO
FROM CLIENTES c
INNER JOIN PEDIDOS p ON p.CLIENTE= c.CODIGO
INNER JOIN LINEAS l ON l.NUM_PEDIDO=p.NUM
INNER JOIN PRODUCTOS pr ON pr.CODIGO=l.PRODUCTO
GROUP BY c.CODIGO,  pr.NOMBRE
ORDER BY c.CODIGO;
```

And it gives me the sum of the last order.

Can you guide me please?

Gracias

<sup>*This question has been translated from Spanish to English with the assistance of Google Translate*</sup>

Answer (score 0):

### SUM and GROUP

If I understood well what you want to know is the total **UNITS** of each product (not money) each customer has bought in all their orders **COMBINED**.

If that is so, in your `SELECT` clause you should `SUM(l.CANTIDAD)` rather than `COUNT()` it, as you want to know the **number of products**, not the number of lines.

The reason your results are **only consistent with individual orders** rather than all of them as a whole is because the orders table '*PEDIDOS*' should be present in the `GROUP BY` clause as well:

```
SELECT c.CODIGO, pr.NOMBRE, SUM(l.CANTIDAD) AS TOTALPEDIDO
FROM CLIENTES c, PEDIDOS p, LINEAS l, PRODUCTOS pr
WHERE p.CLIENTE    =   c.CODIGO
  AND l.NUM_PEDIDO =   p.NUM
  AND pr.CODIGO    =   l.PRODUCTO
GROUP BY c.CODIGO, p.NUM, pr.NOMBRE
ORDER BY c.CODIGO;
```